# Regular Expression Pattern (match URL)

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression that identify special links.

I have an array with links, for example this one

```
array[1] = "http://domain.com/dfdf"
array[2] = "http://domain.com/dfgf"
array[3] = "http://domain2.com/derf"
```

I want to use a regular expression that extract links from this array under a specific domain (for example domain2)

I'll get an array

```
array[1] = "http://domain2.com/derf"
```

I'm looking for the pattern only (I use PHP)

Comment: no, I have the links stored and they are regular, I mean they have the same format "http://domain.com"

Comment: What you like to use domain2 or domain2.com as input? should www.domain2.com also be matched by the pattern, what about https : //ssl.domain2.com/something? What about domain2.net? What about links without http in front of them?

Comment: Regular expressions seem a bit improper for this task. Why not just use the string functions?

Comment: Are you Abid who's originally from kashmir????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regular expression should do it:

```
^http://domain2\.com/
```

And converted into PCRE with `/` as delimiter:

```
/^http:\/\/domain2\.com\//
```

But you can use another character if you want:

```
~^http://domain2\.com/~
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
(?<!")http://domain2.com[^"]+
```

Answer (score 0):

This will match https as well as http links:

```
#^https?://domain2\.com/#
```